# Importing a class and calling a method

Tags: python

I am using Eclipse for Python programming.

In my project, I have a file: main.py. This file is located in the root of the project files hierarchy. In the root itself, I created a folder with the name Classes in which I have a class file named: PositionWindow.py. This file contains a class PositionWindow and the class itself contains a function named: Center().

In main.py, I want to import this class [PositionWindow] and later call that function Center in the appropriate place.

I am not able to import that class correctly in main.py and not following how to call that function later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating  "folder" in the root of your project, create a "package". Simply create a blank file called `__init__.py` and you should be able to import your module in main.py.

```
import Classes.PositionWindow

p = Classes.PositionWindow.PositionWindow()

p.Center()
```

However, you should read up on modules and packages, because your structure indicates that your approach may be flawed. First, a class doesn't have to be in a separate .py file like it does in Java. Further, your packages/modules/functions/methods should all be in lower case. Only class names should be in Upper case.

Comment: What is the role of this blank file __init__.py?

Comment: It indicates that the folder is a python package. This is all discussed in the python tutorial.

Comment: I tried: from Classes import PositionWindow ? How it differs from what you wrote above?

Comment: Like Java and C#, is it compulsory to name the package name same as that of the class name and in case-sensitive way?

Comment: No, @nosklo's answer mentions this. Packges, modules, and classes have no required relation to each other. You really should go through the tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be programming in java, still. I understand that you used java for a long time, but this is no longer java. This is python...

- Python doesn't have directories. It has [packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)
- Python doesn't have class files. It has [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#modules).
- You can have multiple classes in a module.
- You can have multiple modules in a package.

I suggest you read at least the [python basic tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/) (specially the [part about packages and modules](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)) so you can learn python, instead of trying to guess the language.

About the structure of your project, there's [this article](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html) which is pretty good, and shows you how to do it.

*shameless copy paste:*

> ## Filesystem structure of a Python project
>
> *by [Jp Calderone](https://www.blogger.com/profile/15144405957500773467)*
>
> **Do:**
>
> - name the directory something related to your project. For example, if your
>     project is named "Twisted", name the
>     top-level directory for its source
>     files `Twisted`. When you do releases,
>     you should include a version number
>     suffix: `Twisted-2.5`.
> - create a directory `Twisted/bin` and put your executables there, if you
>     have any. Don't give them a `.py`
>     extension, even if they are Python
>     source files. Don't put any code in
>     them except an import of and call to a
>     main function defined somewhere else
>     in your projects.
> - If your project is expressable as a single Python source file, then put it
>     into the directory and name it
>     something related to your project. For
>     example, `Twisted/twisted.py`. If you
>     need multiple source files, create a
>     package instead (`Twisted/twisted/`,
>     with an empty
>     `Twisted/twisted/__init__.py`) and place
>     your source files in it. For example,
>     `Twisted/twisted/internet.py`.
> - put your unit tests in a sub-package of your package (note - this means
>     that the single Python source file
>     option above was a trick - you always
>     need at least one other file for your
>     unit tests). For example,
>     `Twisted/twisted/test/`. Of course, make
>     it a package with
>     `Twisted/twisted/test/__init__.py`.
>     Place tests in files like
>     `Twisted/twisted/test/test_internet.py`.
> - add `Twisted/README` and `Twisted/setup.py` to explain and
>     install your software, respectively,
>     if you're feeling nice.
>
> **Don't:**
>
> - put your source in a directory called `src` or `lib`. This makes it hard
>     to run without installing.
> - put your tests outside of your Python package. This makes it hard to
>     run the tests against an installed
>     version.
> - create a package that only has a `__init__.py` and then put all your code into `__init__.py`. Just make a module
>     instead of a package, it's simpler.
> - try to come up with magical hacks to make Python able to import your module
>     or package without having the user add
>     the directory containing it to their
>     import path (either via `PYTHONPATH` or
>     some other mechanism). You will not
>     correctly handle all cases and users
>     will get angry at you when your
>     software doesn't work in their
>     environment.

Comment: Thanks for the same. Reading it.

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud thanks for the report, I fixed the links.

Answer (score 1):

So you have this file layout:

- /main.py
- /Classes/PositionWindow.py (with Center inside it)

You have two choices:

- Add "Classes" to your Python Path, allowing you to import PositionWindow.py directly.
- Make "Classes" a package (possibly with a better name).

To add the Classes folder to your Python Path, set PYTHONPATH as an environment variable to include it. This works like your shell's PATH -- when you import PositionWindow, it will look through all the directories in your Python Path to find it.

Alternatively, if you add a blank file:

```
Classes/__init__.py
```

You can import the package and its contents like so in main.py:

```
import Classes.PositionWindow
x = Classes.PositionWindow.Center()
```

Comment: Is there no need to create an instance of the Class? I guess it should be.

Comment: "x = Classes.PositionWindow.Center()" creates the instance.